# Is the SMB service enabled by default upon fresh Windows 7 deployment?

Tags: smb, windows-7

I'm curious as over several years ever since I started researching about computer security, SMB has been a place where remote code execution happens the most on the windows OS. Therefore I am wondering if the Windows 7 SP1 installer has port 135 and port 445 opened by default?

Comment: Yes it is. But I would vote to move this question to serverfault.se, it is more appropriate there.

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/1211055/what-is-the-implication-of-ms17-010-patch-and-smbv1-deactivation-related-to-wann

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/1209909/how-to-protect-my-window-from-wanna-cry-wanna-crypt-ransomware-attack/1209910#1209910

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/44828/am-i-affected-by-the-windows-vista-smbv2-flaw/44830#44830